# rspec shared_examples_for method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this controller spec file.

```
describe BriefNotesController do
  render_views

  before(:all) do
    @customer=Factory(:customer)
    @project=Factory(:project_started, :owner => @customer)
  end

  context 'get :new' do

    it 'should redirect to login page for not signed in users' do
      get :new, :project_id => @project.id
      response.should new_user_session_path
    end


  end

  context 'get :create' do

    it 'should redirect to login page for not signed in users' do
      post :create, {:project_id => @project.to_param, :brief_note => Factory.attributes_for(:brief_note, :project_id => @project.id)}
      response.should redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
end
```

In these tests I repeat the same authentication test for each action and thus I want to recode it with dry way.I tried to recode this test with `shared_examples_for` method but I didn't handle with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this can work

```
shared_examples_for 'redirects to login page if not signed in' do

  context 'get :new' do
    it 'should redirect to login page for not signed in users' do
      get :new, :project_id => resource.id
      response.should redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end

  context 'get :create' do
    it 'should redirect to login page for not signed in users' do
      post :create, resource_params
      response.should redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end
end
```

You would use it like this:

```
describe BriefNoteController do
  let(:customer) { Factory(:customer) }
  let(:project) { Factory(:project_started, :owner => customer) }

  let(:resource) { project }
  let(:resource_params) do
    {
      :project_id => project.to_param,
      :brief_note => Factory.attributes_for(:brief_note, :project_id => project.id)
    }
  end

  it_behaves_like 'redirects to login page if not signed in'
end
```